# Is it possible to make 'Folders' view default in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I started to have a lot of build pipelines it has become more comfortable to use 'Folders' view instead of 'Recent'. But it is too annoying to switch it all the time. Is it possible to configure 'Folders' view be default one? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this is ***not possible***.

What might help you is enabling the new preview feature for [Multi-stage pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). To do this, click your profile picture on the top right, click 'Preview features' and enable 'Multi-stage pipelines'.

This new view *doesn't* allow you to set the default view to folder view. However, it *does* give you the option to select 'Folder view' on the top right (next to the search box). This *changes the URL*, which enables you to create a bookmark that starts in Folder view automatically.

Your URL should look something like
`https://dev.azure.com/{organization_name}/{project_name}/_build?view=pipelines&option=folders`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to make 'Folders' view default in Azure Pipelines?

Agree with rickvdbosch, we could not set the 'Folders' view as default, at least for now.

Some other communities raised the same requirement earlier on the Developer Community, and this requirement has been passed to product team, you can check the details from the ticket:

[Builds - Pipelines should default to the folder view if you have one or more folders](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/385607/builds-pipelines-should-default-to-the-folder-view.html)

Note:*You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.*

Hopw this helps.

Comment: Thanks again Leo :)